# Bootstrap fixed top navbar overlaps the vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a fixed-top navbar with Bootstrap.
But the part over the vertical scrollbar that should be visible above the navbar disappears under the navbar.

Live preview of the issue:
http://thenlghost.github.io/Good-Guy-Games/

What is should be:
http://prntscr.com/6df693

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete the overflow line from your body,html css style:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```